# how to send multi variable in request mode in php?

Tags: php, html, get

I have a table that fetch its data by `while` loop. This `while` writes to an Ajax page. Each loop of `while` fetched data showed in table of GUI. One cell of this table has a picture that when a user clicks it should send 2 two variables  to another page by `GET` request. I can send one variable easily but for two or more have problem.

```
    while(($row=$result->fetch_assoc())!=NULL )
  {
     $zamen_id=$row['zamen_id'];
     $person_id=$row['queue_id'];
  $_SESSION['edit_user_queue_no_verifyzamen']=1;

      $display_string.= "<tr class='success'>";
      $display_string.= "<td >".$radif."</td>" ;
      $display_string.= "<td >".$row['prsID']."</td>" ;
      $_SESSION['prs_noselectzamen']=$row['prsID'];
      include('../inf_emp.php');
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['AccID']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$name_nozamen."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$family_nozamen."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['telvam']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".number_format($row['sarmaie'])."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".number_format($row['sahm'])."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['prszamen']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['zamen_name']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['zamen_family']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['telzamen']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['YearReq']."/".$row['MonthReq']."/".$row['DayReq']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td >".$row['predicit_month']."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="<td ><a href='edit_user_queue.php?req_iddel_queue_noverify= ".$person_id.",req_iddel_queue_zaman_noverify=".$zamen_id."'  >"."<img src='../images/delete.JPG' alt='delete' />"."</td>" ;
      $display_string.="</tr>";
      $radif+=1;

}// end while
```

Best Regrads

Comment: Don't seperate with `,` use `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Update the line of code as below. The char , should be replaced by & to seperate each variables

```
$display_string.="<td ><a href='edit_user_queue.php?req_iddel_queue_noverify= ".$person_id."&req_iddel_queue_zaman_noverify=".$zamen_id."'  >"."<img src='../images/delete.JPG' alt='delete' />"."</td>" ;
```